# Getting Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Android classes not found error. What is causing it?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

I'm developing an app in which I am using `firebase` as `BaaS`.

The problem is that I am getting this error: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Android classes not found. Are you using the firebase-client-android artifact?` on this line `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);`.

Here's `FirebaseApplication.java` file's code:

```
public class FirebaseApplication extends android.app.Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    }
}
```

Here's `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {

        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 5
            versionName "0.4"
            multiDexEnabled true;
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
compile 'com.firebase:geofire:1.1.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.1'
compile 'io.github.yavski:fab-speed-dial:1.0.4'
compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am unable to figure out the problem here.

Comment: Have you registered the class in manifest file?

Comment: Can you show your build.gradle file?

Comment: @AnandBarnwal `FirebaseApplication.java` isn't an activity. It can't be declared in manifest file.

Comment: @HammadNasir Sorry, my mistake

Comment: @chrynan checkout the edited question, please.

Comment: Make sure you have Google Play Services properly installed and specified in your grade files. Also, make sure you have the Firebase core library stated in your dependencies. Follow their new doc for getting started: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk

Comment: @chrynan you can see the gradle file in the question. Is there any problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using legacy Firebase, which GeoFire 1.1.0 imports (You should migrate from GeoFire 1.1.0 to Geofire 2.X aswell).

Instead of:

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
```

Use:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, FirebaseOptions.fromResource(this));
```